# Woocommerce search by attributes not works fine

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I developed a search by attributes in WooCommerce and everything seems to be okay. But one attribute is not working in the search. The only difference that I find is that is an alphabetical attribute and the others are numeric.

For example, [this URL](http://neumaticos.7vidas.com.ar/?s=&post_type=product&product_cat=neumaticos&categories=neumaticos&pa_vehiculo=&pa_ancho=175&pa_talon=&pa_rodado=) returns the results correctly but when I search by vehiculo (*pa_vehiculo*) returns all the products.

Why does that happen?

Here is the code, a plugin for a widget:

```
// The filter for some categories

function pf_get_filter_options( $title, $taxonomy ) {

    global $wp_query;

    $options = '' . $title . '';

    $data = get_terms( $taxonomy );

    foreach ( $data as $term ) {

        // Skip some weird terms
        switch ( $taxonomy ) {
            case 'product_cat':
                if( in_array($term->slug, array('promociones')) )
                    continue( 2 );
                break;

        }

        $selected = isset( $wp_query->query_vars[$taxonomy] )  && $wp_query->query_vars[$taxonomy] == $term->slug;
        $options .= '<option value="' . $term->slug . '"' . $selected . '>' . $term->slug . '</option>';

    }

    return $options;

}


// the front-end display and the script for change search by categories because have different attributes

/**
     * Front-end display of widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::widget()
     *
     * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
     * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ) . $args['after_title'];
        }
        ?>

        <form id="form-neumaticos" action="<?php echo site_url( '/' ); ?>" class="search2"  style="display:block">
             <input type="hidden" name="s" value=""/>
             <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product"/>
             <input type="hidden" name="product_cat" value="neumaticos"/>

             <div class="search_box">

                 <div class="select-categories-content-neumatic">   
                 <label>TIPO</label>
                 <select id="select-categories-neumaticos" class="selectBox" name="categories" placeholder="Seleccione">
                 <option selected>neumaticos</option>
                 <option>llantas</option>
                 <option>accesorios</option>

                 <!-- <?php echo pf_get_filter_options( 'category-name', 'product_cat' ); ?> -->
                 </select>
                </div>

             <div id="select-neumaticos">

                 <div class="select-categories-content">        
                 <label>VEHICULO</label>
                 <select class="selectBox selectneumaticos" name="pa_vehiculo">
                    <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                 <?php echo pf_get_filter_options( 'vehiculo', 'pa_vehiculo' ); ?>
                 </select>
                </div>

                 <div class="select-categories-content">    
                 <label>ANCHO</label>
                 <select class="selectBox selectneumaticos" name="pa_ancho">
                 <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                 <?php echo pf_get_filter_options( 'ancho', 'pa_ancho' ); ?>
                 </select>
                </div>

                 <div class="select-categories-content">    
                 <label>TALON</label>
                 <select class="selectBox selectneumaticos" name="pa_talon">
                <option value="">Seleccione</option>    
                 <?php echo pf_get_filter_options( 'talón', 'pa_talon' ); ?>
                 </select>
                </div>

                 <div class="select-categories-content">    
                 <label>RODADO</label>
                 <select class="selectBox selectneumaticos" name="pa_rodado">
                <option value="">Seleccione</option>    
                 <?php echo pf_get_filter_options( 'rodado', 'pa_rodado' ); ?>
                 </select>
                </div>

             </div>
                <button class="search-button" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
             </div>
        </form>

        <form id="form-llantas" action="<?php echo site_url( '/' ); ?>" class="search2" style="display:none;">
             <input type="hidden" name="s" value=""/>
             <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product"/>
             <input type="hidden" name="product_cat" value="llantas"/>


             <div class="search_box">

                 <div class="select-categories-content">    
                 <label>TIPO</label>
                 <select id="select-categories-llantas" class="selectBox" name="categories">
                 <option >neumaticos</option>
                 <option selected>llantas</option>
                 <option>accesorios</option>
                 <!-- <?php echo pf_get_filter_options( 'category-name', 'product_cat' ); ?> -->
                 </select>
                </div>

             <div id="select-llantas">

                 <div class="select-categories-content">    
                 <label>VEHICULO</label>
                 <select class="selectBox selectllantas" name="pa_vehiculo">
                 <option value="">Seleccione</option>   
                 <?php echo pf_get_filter_options( 'vehiculo', 'pa_vehiculo' ); ?>
                 </select>
                </div>

                <div class="select-categories-content">
                 <label>RODADO</label>
                 <select class="selectBox selectllantas" name="pa_rodado">
                <option value="">Seleccione</option>    
                 <?php echo pf_get_filter_options( 'rodado', 'pa_rodado' ); ?>
                 </select>
                </div>

                <div class="select-categories-content">
                 <label>AGUJEROS</label>         
                 <select class="selectBox selectllantas" name="pa_agujeros">
                <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                 <?php echo pf_get_filter_options( 'agujeros', 'pa_agujeros' ); ?>
                 </select>
                </div>

                <div class="select-categories-content">
                 <label>PCD</label>      
                 <select class="selectBox selectllantas" name="pa_pcd">
                <option value="">Seleccione</option>    
                 <?php echo pf_get_filter_options( 'pcd', 'pa_pcd' ); ?>
                 </select>
                </div>

            </div>

                 <button class="search-button" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

             </div>
        </form>

        <?php
        echo $args['after_widget'];
        ?>

    <script>

jQuery.noConflict()(function ($){
     $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#select-categories-neumaticos').on('change', function() {

        if ( this.value == 'neumaticos')

        {

        $("#form-llantas").hide();


        $("#form-neumaticos").show();


    }

        if ( this.value == 'llantas')

        {


        $("#form-llantas").show();


        $("#form-neumaticos").hide();

    }

})

        $('#select-categories-llantas').on('change', function(){


        if ( this.value == 'llantas');

        {

        $("#form-neumaticos").hide();


        $("#form-llantas").show();


        }
        if ( this.value == 'neumaticos')

        {

        $("#form-neumaticos").show();


        $("#form-llantas").hide();


        }
    })

    $('#select-categories-neumaticos').on('change', function(){


        if (this.value == 'accesorios')

        {

             window.location = 'http://neumaticos.7vidas.com.ar/index.php/categoria-producto/accesorios/';
        }
    });
    $('#select-categories-llantas').on('change', function(){


        if (this.value == 'accesorios')

        {

             window.location = 'http://localhost/neumaticos/index.php/categoria-producto/accesorios/';
        }
    });

    });
});
    </script>

<?php       
    }
```

Everything works except the attribute *vehiculo*, which returns all results.

Comment: please update your question with your code/snippets?

Comment: Hi! here i update de code, if you find something please tell me!

Comment: This is out of my expertise but some will help you out. and I think there is an js error near ` if (this.value == 'llantas')` there is a extra `;`.

Comment: Thanks Raunak! i corrected that mistake but still the search not works correctly, if someone find something, please tell me! 

Thank y very much!

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution! for the search by attributes works seems has to be checked "Enable this if you want this attribute to have product archives in your store."  in attributes.
I checked it and the search works fine.

Thank Raunak for your help!h